# Gatsby: Why Do I (Or Do I Even?) Need to Use exports.onCreateNode to Create Pages?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

All of the examples in the Gatsby documentation seem to assume you want to define an `exports.onCreateNode` first to parse your data, and then define a separate `exports.createPages` to do your routing.

However, that seems needlessly complex.  A much simpler option would seem to be to just use the `graphql` option provided to `createPages`:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;
  const { data } = await graphql(query);
  // use data to build page
  data.someArray.forEach(datum => 
    createPage({ path: `/some/path/${datum.foo}`, component: SomeComponent }));
```

However, when I do that, I get an error:

> TypeError: filepath.includes is not a function

I assume this is because my `path` prop for `createPage` is a string and it should be "slug".  However, all the approaches for generating slugs seem to involve doing that whole `exports.onCreateNode` thing.

Am I missing a simple solution for generating valid slugs from a path string?  Or am I misunderstanding Gatsby, and for some reason I *need* to use `onCreateNode` every time I use `createPage`?

Comment: Do you have any examples of the Gatsby documentation you are referring to?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-slugs-for-pages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Do I Need to Use exports.onCreateNode to Create Pages?

You do not.

Gatsby heavily uses GraphQL behind the scenes. The Gatsby documentation is about teaching users that many of the features in Gatsby are often only available via GraphQL.

You can create pages without GraphQL as you do in answer with `data.someArray.forEach ...` but that is not the intended way. By skipping `createNodeField` you will not be able to query for these fields within your page queries. If you don't need these fields via GraphQL then your solution is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, but I *am* still able to use the GraphQL data that way: I just pass `data` as a context variable to the page.  I still really don't understand the point of `onCreateNode` and it's extra complexity for (seemingly) no extra benefit.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the error I mentioned:

> TypeError: filepath.includes is not a function

Wasn't coming from the `path` prop at all: it was coming from the (*terribly* named) `component` prop ... which *does not* take a component function/class!  Instead it takes a *path to a component* (why they don't call the prop `componentPath` is just beyond me!)

But all that aside, once I fixed "component" to (*sigh*) no longer be a component, I was able to get past that error and create pages ... and it turns out the whole `onCreateNode` thing *is* unnecessary.